# Can ASP.NET session remember objects?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I start my question from an example. I think it will be more simple.

What i want to do, is send REQUEST_1 from my Android device to asp page, which is waiting for JSON request, for example {"Year":2012}. Page takes this json string, and saves it to the object (example arraylist).
After a minute, I send REQUEST_2 to the same ASP page with data: {"Command","WhatIsCurrentYear"}, and I then want to get response: {"Year",2012} (which should still be stored in the arraylist).

Is there a chance to do this?

Comment: This sounds like the very definition of ASP.NET session variables

Comment: Sorry, it was a bit wrong question. I have changed it a bit :) I want the objects in session to be remembered :)

Comment: @Augis: the point still stands. The whole point of the Session object is that it persists for the whole Session...

Comment: @DanPichelman: That sounds like an answer, not a comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session has a property Session.TimeOut. Session expires after the time expires. By default in asp.net session Timeout time is 20 mintues Also if user closes the browser session also expires if it's mode is InProc ( Cookies or without cookies ). In InProc session provider IIS could recycle the application pool at any moment (period of inactivity, certain CPU/memory thresholds are reached, ...) without warning voiding the contents of this session.
Variables are initialized on every post back, so if previously you had saved data in an array list object it is lost. To save data during postbacks you can use ViewState.

Comment: Also don't forget to mention that if you are using InProc session provider (storing session data in-memory, which is the default provider), IIS could recycle the application pool at any moment (period of inactivity, certain CPU/memory thresholds are reached, ...) without warning voiding the contents of this session.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class for accessing the session

```
public static IPerson User
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null || HttpContext.Current.Session[UserConstant] == null)
            return new Student();
        return (IPerson)HttpContext.Current.Session[UserConstant];
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[UserConstant] = value;
    }
}
```

You can replace IPerson with whatever object you want.